# How to compress and email test reports generated in cucumber with selenium webdriver

Tags: java, extentreports

In my project I am using cucumber with junit, maven and selenium webdriver inclusive with java and extent report.
My extent report is generated in an folder 'output' and within the same folder screenshot of failed test-cases are also saved. 
After execution of test and generation of report I want to compress the folder 'output' into zip file and mail it.

**Issue : At the instance when my code converts the file into zip format, the test-report is not yet generated  (as it generates after completion of all test cases) so when 'output' folder is compressed it only contains the failed screenshot and same is being mailed..
Please suggest**
[this is my runner file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gz5JI.png)
[this is my hooks class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMTFw.png)

### This is my runner class...............

```
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"featurefiles/DefineStaffType.feature"}
        , glue = {"stepdefinitions"}
        , monochrome = true
        , plugin = {"pretty:STDOUT",
        "json:target/cucumber.json",
        "junit:target/cucumber.xml",
        "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"}
        , tags = {"@Scenario1, @Scenario2, @Scenario3"}
)
public class DefineStaffTypeRunner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void reportSetup ( ) throws IOException, EmailException {

        Reporter.loadXMLConfig ( new File ( "configuration\\extentconfig.xml" ) );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "User Name", System.getProperty ( "user.name" ) );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "Time Zone", System.getProperty ( "user.timezone" ) );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "64 Bit", "Windows 10" );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "3.1.0", "Selenium" );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "1.9", "Maven" );
        Reporter.setSystemInfo ( "1.9", "Java Version" );
        Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput ( "Define Staff Type " );


        FileConversion.convertToZip ( "output" );


        new MailHandlingUtility ( ).sendMailWithAttachment ( );
    }
}
```

### This is my hooks class

```
public class CucumberHooks extends GenericBaseClass {
    DriverMethods dm = new DriverMethods ( );
    CaptureScreenshot cs = new CaptureScreenshot ( );
    static MailHandlingUtility mhu = new MailHandlingUtility ( );

    @Before
    public void launchBrowser (Scenario currentscenario) throws IOException {
        this.scenario = currentscenario;
        driver = getCurrentDriver ( );
        dm.maximizeWindow ( );
    }

    @After
    public void tearDownScenario (Scenario currentscenario) throws IOException, EmailException {
        scenario.write ( "Scenario is finished" + currentscenario );
        cs.catureScreenshot ( (Scenario) scenario );
        driver.close ( );
        driver.quit ( );
        driver = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of converting file into zip format if I attach report and image separately. same block of code works fine.

Comment: Please, add your code directly to the question as text (not as link to image)

Comment: I had updated my code directly....